# VBA Chart x-axis: why is it row no. rather than values?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a chart on excel using VBA. However the x-axis keeps showing row number rather than the value in the row. Here is the code that I currently have. Am I doing something wrong? The y-axis is correct though

```
If CheckBox4.Value = False Then
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then 'S11 S22
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    With ActiveChart
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "S11 & S22"
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Frequency/GHz"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "/dB"
        .SetSourceData Source:=Range("B2:T5")

        Do Until .SeriesCollection.Count = 0
            .SeriesCollection(1).Delete
        Loop

        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "S11"
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range("A9:A" & j)
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = Range("B9:B" & j)
            .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryGridLinesMinorMajor)
            .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueGridLinesMinorMajor)
         '   .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisLogScale)
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(2).Name = "S22"
        .SeriesCollection(2).XValues = Range("A9:A" & j)
        .SeriesCollection(2).Values = Range("H9:H" & j)
        With .Parent
            .Height = 300
            .Width = 500
            .Top = 50
            .Left = 600
        End With
    End With
End If
```

Thank you in advance guys!

Answer (score 1):

Try replcaing

```
.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range("A9:A" & j)
```

with:

```
.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=" & Range("A9:A" & j).Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)
```

Comment: Hmm it still didn't work! X-axis still reflects row number (9-200 in my case) and not the values inside the cells

Comment: when you run it in debug mode, what is the value of `j`? if you add `Debug.Print Range("A9:A" & j).Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)` what are you getting ?

Comment: I have found a solution to it! Turns out the last value which is row j is "END" which isn't numeric hence the chart was plotted against row number. I used j = j -1 and it worked! Thank you very much for your help anyway!! ^^

Comment: @Jane, it is still better to use the method suggested here because it is "dynamic". Your method is static so if the values in the `Range("A9:A" & j)` are changed later, this change will not be reflected in the chart and you will need to re-run the macro!